# G.Raphael Dynamic Pie Chart code not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, raphael

I'm new to the Raphael, so I'm trying to learn some things through the tutorials that are available.

I'm stuck with a problem, where I simply copy/paste the Source Code from Raphael's site:
http://g.raphaeljs.com/piechart2.html

I right-clicked to see the source code and I copy/pasted in my notepad++. I did add the needed JS and CSS files, everything is the same.

MY CODE:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo-print.css" media="print">
        <script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="g.raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="g.pie-min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="pie"></div>
    <script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var r = Raphael("holder"),
                pie = r.piechart(320, 240, 100, [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10], { legend: ["%%.%% - Enterprise Users", "IE Users"], legendpos: "west", href: ["http://raphaeljs.com", "http://g.raphaeljs.com"]});

                r.text(320, 100, "Interactive Pie Chart").attr({ font: "20px sans-serif" });
                /*pie.hover(function () {
                    this.sector.stop();
                    this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy);*/

                    /*if (this.label) {
                        this.label[0].stop();
                        this.label[0].attr({ r: 7.5 });
                        this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 800 });
                    }
                }, function () {
                    this.sector.animate({ transform: 's1 1 ' + this.cx + ' ' + this.cy }, 500, "bounce");

                    if (this.label) {
                        this.label[0].animate({ r: 5 }, 500, "bounce");
                        this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 400 });
                    }*/
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="raphael" id="g.raphael.dmitry.baranovskiy.com">
        <div id="holder"></div>
        <p>
            Pie chart with legend, hyperlinks on two first sectors and hover effect.
        </p>
        <p>
            Demo of <a href="http://g.raphaeljs.com/">gRaphaël</a> JavaScript library.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ignore the "commented lines", this was me trying to debugg my problem. I get the background, but the chart just won't display.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you checked your console?

Answer (score 0):

Give your canvas dimensions.

Instead of:

```
var r = Raphael("holder"),
```

Try using:

```
var r = Raphael("holder", 0, 0, 520, 440),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for your browser settings for Active x controls.There might be appearing a prompt message by the browser when you try to load the page.
Something like:-

"To help protect your security,Internet Explorer has restricted this page from running scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer.click here for options..." 
You need to click on the message & select option- 'Allow Blocked Contents'

As I don't see any problem with your canvas creation or the coordinates.